# Error: Activity class { } does not exist. Error while Launching activity

Tags: java, activity

Я работаю в Android Studio 2.2.2 Простое приложение Hello world спокойно открывается на планшете Sumsung GT3113 (Android 4.2.2) и не запускается на смартфоне mi_4c (Android 5.1.1). Что я только не пробовал: менял драйвера, чистил и перебирал проект, синхронизировал, делал отложенный запуск, переходил на Android Studio 1.5.1 и всё равно ошибка запуска. Народ, что не так? Помогите, пожалуйста.
Привожу файл манифеста и сборки.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.adc2017gmail.testmi4c">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.adc2017gmail.testmi4c"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```